# Redux Firebase: Firebase SDK console

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

```
import  * as firebase from 'firebase'


var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBUyjLkedpKhuxgolrTSjw547k1XkwExcQ",
  authDomain: "posts-2dce0.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://posts-2dce0.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "posts-2dce0",
  storageBucket: "posts-2dce0.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "575596087223"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const database = firebase.database().ref('posts/');
```

Im having an console error here that says: It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/';

i did try everything but it wont work. Still receiving this console warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

instead of the 1st line of your code?

Do you import firebase in any other files?

Comment: Yeap. I did import { database } from '../Firebase'. on my actions.js tried that but im having an error. => TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_firebase_app___default.a.database is not a function

Comment: after adding:
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');

error disappears but i cant see anyhing. my data wont appear

Comment: Only that warning message. Written above.

Comment: @CrisostomoIbarra Is this node.js or web?